# Change the width of a polygon without impacting others

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I would like to draw a polygon as follows. I know how to use pen tool or shape builder tool (1 rectangle + 1 triangle - 1 triangle) to do this.

But when I modify the width of shape by moving the anchor, the angle of the triangle change as well. I don't want it to happen; I'm looking for a way to change the width of the shape easily without impacting anything else.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Draw a single rectangle.
2. Make sure smart guides are ON (under View menu).
3. Hit <kbd>P</kbd> for *Path Tool* and touch the rectangle in these red spots. Smart guides will help you pinpoint the actual centers of left/right edges. Make sure you click on the actual line, not anywhere else (the mouse cursor will highlight this for you). This will add anchor points to the rectangle sides, breaking those segments in two.

[image]

4. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> *Direct Selection Tool* and select these 2 anchor points. Use arrows or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrows to move these anchor points left or right, and adjust your shape.
5. Any resulting segment of the resulting shape can be further adjusted with the *Direct Selection Tool*, by moving the anchor points around.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> to select some of the anchors on one side of the object only. Then you can move the multiple selecton.  Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag will constrain the move horizontally. You can also move the anchors by nudging them with the Arrow keys.

An example

[image]